# Why declaring non thread - volatile parameter in Facebook YearClass

Tags: java, multithreading, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, volatile

I explored Facebook open source [device-year-class](https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class/blob/master/yearclass/src/main/java/com/facebook/device/yearclass/YearClass.java) and found something interesting I wanted to ask.

It's pretty simple class that do some calculating and returns the year of you device

```
public class YearClass {  
.
.

      private volatile static Integer mYearCategory;

          public static int get(Context c) {
            if (mYearCategory == null) {
              synchronized(YearClass.class) { 
                if (mYearCategory == null) {
                  mYearCategory = categorizeByYear(c);
                } 
              } 
            } 
            return mYearCategory;
          }

}
```

Why they check twice the `mYearCategory == null` condition and why this variable declared `volatile`? Its not initialised from different threads and we don't have changes to that value in the app life time, we just retrieve it for the first time... why its so important to make sure we read/write it from/to memory, what would happened if it was without `volatile`. Also why we need to `synchronized` it? there is no risk that other Thread can change it, it's just for reading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Why have static volatile variable?**

If you access a static value through multiple threads, each thread can have its local cached copy. To avoid this you can declare the variable as static volatile and this will force the thread to read each time the global value.

Now coming to your second question. Why is there checking of null twice? This is called double-checked locking optimization.

**What is double checked locking?**

```
          public static int get(Context c) {
            if (mYearCategory == null) {
              synchronized(YearClass.class) { 
                if (mYearCategory == null) {
                  mYearCategory = categorizeByYear(c);
                } 
              } 
            } 
            return mYearCategory;
          }
```

Consider, the first call to get(Context c) will create the object and only the few threads trying to access it during that time need to be synchronized; after that all calls just get a reference to the member variable. Since synchronizing a method could in some extreme cases decrease performance by a factor of 100 or higher,the overhead of acquiring and releasing a lock every time this method is called seems unnecessary: once the initialization has been completed, acquiring and releasing the locks would appear unnecessary. Many programmers have attempted to optimize this situation in the following manner:

1. Check that the variable is initialized (without obtaining the lock). If it is initialized, return it immediately.
2. Obtain the lock.
3. Double-check whether the variable has already been initialized: if another thread acquired the lock first, it may have already done the initialization. If so, return the initialized variable.
4. Otherwise, initialize and return the variable.

Comment: but that variable is not a stock item,not something dynamic or something that can be changed between Threads, Its only returns the device year, I don't see scenario where one Thread get X year and other Thread get Y year that wasn't updated f. n Threads will get the same result always.

Comment: A lock must be obtained in case two threads call get(Context c) simultaneously. Otherwise, either they may both try to create the object at the same time, or one may wind up getting a reference to an incompletely initialized object.

Comment: Thank you for you answer,all clear except the idea to declare that variable as volatile, there is not scenario where 2 Threads can change that value, it has one value for all, why it is so important in that case?

Comment: From the commit history of the file in concern, it appears that the variable can be accessed by two or more threads. Now given that the variable was initially declared as static, it means that each thread can have a copy of the static variable in local cached state. To avoid multiple copies in cache, volatile was introduced later.

Comment: Don't use double checked locking in Java.  It's not a real solution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: I am not saying what you should use or not use. I think the question here was why this was used?

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html   And please remove the down vote if you agree.